# Nodejs printing twice

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here I am trying to extract specific details from a social media site but unfortunately the result or the extracted information is printing twice. So please give me a remedy to solve this issue.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'www.quora.com',
    path: '/directory/'
};

callback = function (response) {
    var str = ''
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {

        var match = str.match(/People(.*?)\/div>/);
        var match1 = match.toString().match(/<a href="\/directory\/page\/(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/g);

        for (var index = 0; index < match1.length; index++) {
            console.log(match1[index]);
        }
    });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback);
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of match in JS is an array where

- First index is the maching string
- Next indexes are capturing groups.

You should have something like this in your console.

```
<a href="/directory/page/something">
something
```

See the official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.

**--- EDIT ---**

Sorry for misunderstanding, I suggests you to edit your question with the console output.
I had a look to the page you're crawling on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/directory/), and I think the origin of the problem is the first regular expression.

You want to select the list of people, but your regular expression takes all the text until the last closing div markup of the page.

With chrome or FF, opens the page, opens the dev console and have a try by ourself :

```
$('body')[0].innerHTML.match('People(.*)\/div>');
```

To make such selection, I suggest to use [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio). This is a very light HTML parser, that provide basic jQuery functionnalities. It will allow you to select the needed divs without using regular expressions:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

...

response.on('end', function () {
   $ = cheerio.load(str);
   var links = $('.letters').first().find('[href]');
   for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
     console.log($(links[i]).attr('href'));
   }
}
```

Comment: `match=str.match(/People(.*?)\/div>/);` match contains "People XXX/div>" and "XXX", and `match1=match.toString().match(/<a href="\/directory\/page\/(.*?)">` match1 contains what I give as example. Can you confirm your input is like my example ?

Comment: fist of all i'm extracting the all people link with the bullet point after that only using the forloop i extract the each and every links with the IDs 
this is what i get 

E:\nodejs>node new3.js
<a href="/directory/page/odZS9K93HEr">A</a>
<a href="/directory/page/qTkupgCwBZu">B</a>
<a href="/directory/page/odZS9K93HEr">A</a>
<a href="/directory/page/qTkupgCwBZu">B</a>

printing twice

Comment: is this correct :

callback = function(response) {
  var cheerio = require('cheerio');
  response.on('data', function (cheerio) {
    str += cheerio;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
  
    var match=str.match(/People(.*?)\/div>/); 

  var match1=match.toString().match(/<a href="\/directory\/page\/(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/g); 

   $ = cheerio.load(str);
   var links = $('.letters').first().find('[href]');
   for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
     console.log($(links[i]).attr('href'));
               }
 
  });
}